# how to scroll the content top and bottom using top and bottom buttons

Tags: button, scroll

please some one helps, how to scroll the content top and bottom using buttons and hidden scroll bar. below my example code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<button onclick="scrollWin(0, 50)">Scroll down</button>
```

Click one of the buttons (multiple times) to scroll the document window.

```
<p>Look at each scrollbar to see the effect.</p>
<p>Click one of the buttons (multiple times) to scroll the document window.</p>
<p>Look at each scrollbar to see the effect.</p>
<button onclick="scrollWin(0, -50)">Scroll up</button><br><br>
<script>
function scrollWin(x, y) {
 window.scrollBy(x, y);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
<style>

button {

border: 0;

border-radius: 2px;

width: 100%;

background-color: #efefef;

}

.my-custom-scrollbar {

position: relative;

height: 200px;

overflow: auto;

}

</style>
```

Comment: Is there even something to be scrolled? By the code you provided, it seems like, there is nothing to scroll really.
EDIT: To make it more clear, please demonstrate, how you use your class '.my-custom-scrollbar', it is not used in <body>.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sm1215/sebgbnr4/ - check the link. we need like same for this . i have copy this code and run my browser, but the scrolling is not working. any idea about this?

Comment: 1 idea: How did you copy that to your browser? It uses jQuery, which is JavaScript library and it needs to be loaded first, before you can use it.

Comment: Do you even use console? (F12)

Comment: 1st thanks for your support.

Comment: Do you even use console?- No, We need to create put top of button and bottom of button and middle is some content .when i click top of button content will scroll and when i click bottom of button will scroll contents. do you have any script for related this.

Comment: $("html, body").animate -this function is not working for using to set height

Comment: You should start using console already. It looks like, that you are just guessing. Also it would be helpful, if you made your own solution in JSFiddle, because some code in your question is missing. What height do you want to set? Because scrollTop is something pretty different. Do you even know, what does $("html, body") does, if not, you should start right here.